# How to round up the number before decimal?

Tags: sql

Can anyone suggest the way to implement this

```sql
Declare @x decimal(22,10)='234323154322.6787654321'
Declare @y decimal(20,10)=@x;
```

Currently giving error:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric.

Comment: I've gone ahead and removed the tag spam here; please only tag the RDBMS you are *really* using. Tagging multiple conflicting technologies makes your question unclear and thus *harder* to answer. It is also unlikely to get your question "more views" and likely to have the opposite effect, where only users who know *all* the RDBMS you have (mis)tagged will entertain the question; that is often a very small portion of the user base. Tag spam is far more likely to result in your question receiving downvotes and/or being closed as unclear. Please [edit] your question to retag the correct RDBMS.

Comment: `234323154322` (with or without the decimal places) will *never* fit in a `decimal(20,10)`; you only have *10 digits* for the integer part of the value, and `234323154322` contains 12 digits. What value are you expecting to store in `@y`?

Comment: wanted to crop 2 digits before decimal, or you can suggest a technique to check the length of the decimal then crop and assign the value.

Comment: So you want `4323154322.6787654321`? [Edit] your question to address the (removed) tags and actually *explain* what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this:

```
Declare @x decimal(22,10)='234323154322.6787654321'
Declare @y decimal(20,10)=@x/100;

SELECT @x,@y
```